# TYPO3: Scheduler for directmail not working

Tags: typo3

I have installed TYPO3 extension "direct_mail", and Im trying to configure the scheduler to automatically invoke the mailer engine, but the task keeps getting delayed (shows the yellow button), and never actually works. What am I missing?

**Cronjob:**

*/15 * * * * /html/cronjobs/scheduler.sh

**scheduler.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
php_cli /home/www/pXXXXXX/html/typo3/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler
```

**Scheduler:**
[image]

**Setup check:**
[image]

Comment: Did you set a cron job for the Scheduler?

Comment: Why do you wrap your command with the additional script ? what happens when you invoke /html/cronjobs/scheduler.sh in the commandline? does it have execution permissions ? `chmod +x /html/cronjobs/scheduler.sh`

Comment: Im using this script because Im using my provider backend to setup the cronjob and it doesnt allow me to write it with a parameter like "scheduler". The script works fine in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing that you didn't configure the Scheduler. In general Scheduler is an extension, which allows you to run TYPO3 tasks easily, however you need to invoke the Scheduler from the system cron to make it working. Checklist:

- in `ADMIN TOOLS` > `Scheduler` choose 'Setup check` from upper select
- Make sure that second frame is green if you didn't create `_cli_scheduler` BE account do it now - it's required
- In third box (`CLI script`) there is a command to run the scheduler from command line
  `/Absolute/path/to/your/typo3-instance/typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler`
  copy it and run in the terminal, to check if it's working
- If everything's ok add the line to your system cron and set some period (ie: every 5 minutes)
- set new timings for your DM task and control after 5 minutes if last execution was done with the cron (in your screenshot currently it's 'Manual')

Comment: I've updated my post. I think all the requirements you mentioned are met.

Comment: I just realized that its working. Im not sure at which point it got fixed, probably when i was checking those points you mentioned. I think the reason why sometimes it looks yellow is because Im checking the status after the "due time" of the task, but before the activation of the cronjob. thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reason. To check when the cron run the Scheduler last time just read the date/time from the first box of `Setup check`

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem, only running the cli scrip returns this http://pastebin.com/WVwx9Q1z . The problem is I didn't set up this Typo3 installation and I can't change it much because it's about 4gb big with data. It's saying that the localconfig.php is missing. Well, that's true, because the folder structure looks like this: http://pastebin.com/6NWQ4cTW . So what do I do?